# update-notifier-common error in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, crash, python3, update-notifier

I always get an error saying `Ubuntu 16.04 has experienced an internal error` when the UI is loading. I checked for the reason and found:-

```
ExecutablePath:-
  /usr/lib/update-notifier/package-data-downloader
Package:-
  update-notifier-common 3.168.8
ProblemType:-
  Crash
Title:-
  package-data-downloader crashed with ImportError in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/debian/deb822.py: No module named 'chardet'
```

#### Traceback:-

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/update-notifier/package-data-downloader", line 24, in <module>
    import debian.deb822
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/debian/deb822.py", line 38, in <module>
 ImportError: No module named 'chardet'
```

---

By this, I could understand nothing but that this problem is of `update-notifier-common`. Please tell me how to solve this problem, reporting the error doesn't help.

Comment: Read the error message carefully: The problem is with a missing python module. Reinstall the `python-debian` package, it provides deb822.py